# How to activate horizontal scrolling inside a div by overflowing its content?

Tags: css, html, horizontal-scrolling

I have the following structure:

```
<div id='container'>
  <div id='cont1' style='width:150px'>Content 1</div>
  <div id='cont2' style='width:150px'>Content 2</div>
  <div id='cont3' style='width:150px'>Content 3</div>
  <div id='cont4' style='width:150px'>Content 4</div>
  <div id='cont5' style='width:150px'>Content 5</div>
</div>
```

I want div `container` to horizontally scroll. I want `cont1` until `cont5` to stay inside `container`. I want to be able to horizontally scroll these 5 divs and, possibly, I want to simply put one `contx` div next to the other exactly as I showed in the code.

The problem is that I cannot achieve this solution. For example consider:

```
<div id='container'>
  <div id='internalcontainer' style='width:750px'>
    <div id='cont1' style='width:150px'>Content 1</div>
    <div id='cont2' style='width:150px'>Content 2</div>
    <div id='cont3' style='width:150px'>Content 3</div>
    <div id='cont4' style='width:150px'>Content 4</div>
    <div id='cont5' style='width:150px'>Content 5</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

What seemed to me quite complicated to do is to obtain the horizontal scroll by simply putting one div next to the other (contant divs). So I tried to put them inside a fixed width container which is placed inside the div that should perform the horizontal scroll. Even this code does not work when i try to style it. My questions are:

- Is it possible to obtain the horizontal scroll with the first structure?
- Is it possible to obtain the horizontal scroll with the second structure?

I tried a lot with css `overflow`, but did not get anything...

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can apply the style `overflow-x:scroll` to your container div if the event onmouseover is triggered and reset it to `overflow-x:hidden` if onmouseout is triggered.

#### edit

here's what you need to add to your container divs:

```
<div id='container' onmouseover='this.style["overflowX"]="scroll";'  onmouseout='this.style["overflowX"]="visible";'>
    ...
</div>
```

try it yourself: http://jsfiddle.net/bukfixart/qX8Cx/

Comment: Works on every browser, nearly all versions. Even on IE as far back as v5. **[Browser Support](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/overflow-x#Browser_compatibility)**

Comment: but if you are using it via javascript, it doesn't make your site invalid

Comment: Sorry bukfixart but it does not work... furthermore the jsfiddle as well does not work... :(

Answer (score 0):

Yes is possible with both structures. I'll illustrate the first one since it is less verbose. I'll use flex box CSS3 feature:

```css
#container {
  display: inline-flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}
```

```html
<div id='container'>
  <div id='cont1' style='width:150px'>Content 1</div>
  <div id='cont2' style='width:150px'>Content 2</div>
  <div id='cont3' style='width:150px'>Content 3</div>
  <div id='cont4' style='width:150px'>Content 4</div>
  <div id='cont5' style='width:150px'>Content 5</div>
</div>
```

If you want a scroll bar in the container itself you can add:

```css
#container {
  overflow-x: scroll;
}
```